# Web Scraping LXML and requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, lxml, python-3.7

I have just started learning how to do some web scraping using LXML and requests. I want to program an app that will tell me what movies are on in a particular cinema.

The [movie list](https://www.eventcinemas.com.au/Sessions#cinemas=86).

Here is my code:

```
import requests
from lxml import html

# Getting the Page
HTML = requests.get('https://www.eventcinemas.com.au/Sessions#cinemas=86')
doc = html.fromstring(HTML.content)

# Getting the Movie
path1 = doc.xpath('//div[@class="body-content"]')[0]
path2 = path1.xpath('.//div[@class="content"]')[0]
path3 = path2.xpath('.//div[@id="first-dates"]')[0]
path4 = path3.xpath('.//div[@class="split-content"]')[0]
path5 = path4.xpath('.//div[@id="session-list"]')[0]
```

I am getting stuck trying to get all the way to the movie titles.
I have a feeling it has something to do with the class, but am not sure:

```
<div class="movie-container list-view"...
```

I have also tried this but it gives me no value:

```
path6 = path5.xpath('.//div[@class="movie-container list-view"]')
print(path6)
```

However, the output from the print is nothing, and from what I understand, that means that it cannot find a directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use simple request e parsing libraries for dynamic pages.

Note that there are mainly two types of pages, namely:

- **Static pages** are plain human-readable text, usually formatted with html, xml, json etc.
- **Dynamic pages** are pages whose construction performs "on the fly" with asynchronous requests.

On Google Chrome, in developer's tools > network, you can watch the requests that were made to build de page.

There, for exemple, que can find this link: https://www.eventcinemas.com.au/Cinemas/GetSessions?cinemaIds=86 . Very often, when you want to query some information from a website, there is an easier way than parsing (dirty) html.

However, when you have no other option aside from reading the page, you need to simulate it as any browser. For this purpose there are libraries as selenium webdriver, https://pypi.org/project/selenium/, though very heavy for RAM and time.